# readding removed panel in jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Let me first of all explain me problem,

I have a jpanel pnlBttns in my frame in the first view, which has 2 buttons as you can see in the image.

[image]

When clicked on <kbd>Edit Video</kbd>, this jpanel is removed, and i add another jpanel named editPanel to my frame, as shown in the image below,

[image: pnlBttns]

Now, **here's the problem**,

When I click on the back button, I remove back the editPanel and show the pnlBttns. But what my frame shows is as below, the two buttons are there but with no text.

[image: editPanel].

The problem is strange because when clicked again on edit video button(though its empty), it takes me to editPanel, and shows all keys fine and normal. So why is the pnlBttns not shown properly, its not getting "repainted" properly.

**Code**,

## sscce.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;



public class sscce extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Editor");             //Open window.
    String state = new String("wait");
    //Panels
    JPanel pnlBttns = new JPanel();
    JPanel editPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel uploadPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel welcome = new JPanel();
    JPanel f = new JPanel();
    JPanel head = new JPanel();

    //Buttons
    JButton button1 = new JButton("E");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("U");
    JButton cut = new JButton("Cut");
    JButton trim = new JButton("Trim");
    JButton audio = new JButton("Audio");
    JButton done = new JButton("Done");
    JButton play = new JButton();
    JButton stop = new JButton();

    public sscce() {
        //Customize Window to record.
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setLocation(100,100);
        frame.setSize(1200,700);
    // ****On closing window event
        pnlBttns.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Paddings
        editPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(30, 10, 30, 10), new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)));
        uploadPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(30, 10, 30, 10), new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)));
        pnlBttns.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(80, 10, 340, 10), new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)));

        //Set commands for Buttons 
        button1.setToolTipText("Start Editing Video"); 
        button1.setActionCommand("edit");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.setToolTipText("Upload this Video"); 
        button2.setActionCommand("upload");
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        pnlBttns.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);          
        pnlBttns.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(pnlBttns, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //create edit panel
        editPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(editPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        done.setToolTipText("Go back");
        done.setActionCommand("done");
        done.addActionListener(this);
        cut.setToolTipText("Cut Video into parts");
        cut.setActionCommand("cut");
        cut.addActionListener(this);
        trim.setToolTipText("Remove parts of Video");
        trim.setActionCommand("trim");
        trim.addActionListener(this);
        audio.setToolTipText("Edit audio of Video");
        audio.setActionCommand("audio");
        audio.addActionListener(this);
        editPanel.add(audio);
        editPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        editPanel.add(cut);
        editPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        editPanel.add(trim);
        editPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 50)));
        editPanel.add(done);
        frame.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        editPanel.setVisible(false);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.add(pnlBttns, BorderLayout.EAST);
        //create upload panel.
        addVideo();
    }

    public void addVideo()
        {   head.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            f.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            JPanel videoPanel = new JPanel();
            f.add(videoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(head, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new sscce();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        if ("edit".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {

            state = "edit";
            pnlBttns.setVisible(false);
            editPanel.setVisible(true);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();

        } else if ("done".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

                editPanel.setVisible(false);
                pnlBttns.setVisible(true);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();

        }   
    }   
}
```

another version,

To hide pnlBttns,

```
state = "edit";
frame.remove(pnlBttns);
frame.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

To show it again,

```
frame.remove(editPanel);
frame.add(pnlBttns);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

I have checked and am 100% sure, I am no where updating the text of the two buttons.

What I guess is the problem, may be size of panel.

What you see in black is my video player, its size gets increased when pnlBttns is removed, since editPanel is thinner, when added back, mediaPlayer also overlaps a little with the pnlBttns. Can that be the problem, still the text should have been there. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Try using `setVisible(false)` rather than removing it, then when you want it to appear again, use `setVisible(true)`

Comment: okay. that may help. let me try. @StormeHawke

Comment: @StormeHawke: maybe that should be an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - perhaps you're right lol

Comment: No, doesn't help. setVisible(flase) hides the panels, but again setting it to true, doesn't show it back. @StormeHawke

Comment: setVisible(false) hides the panels, but again setting it to true, doesn't show it back. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
state = "edit";
frame.remove(pnlBttns);
frame.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

To show it again,

```
frame.remove(editPanel);
frame.add(pnlBttns, BorderLayout.EAST);    //May be you need to add this to east
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

PS: My 100th answer.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I see code using the remove/add methods I recommend that you should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead. It will manage the display of the proper panel.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to show it in tabs, I would prefer that once the user has finished editing, pressing done and going back to the main page.

Comment: @jeez: CardLayout is perfect for what you just described. 1+ to camickr.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Looks to me width is the culprit. Please see comments on Mukesh's answer. But I really don't want a tabbed structure. I wish the user can click on edit button and he sees the editing tools, then he clicks on Done, goes back to main panel, where he has option to upload. I respect his suggestion, but its just that I don't want that design.

Comment: @jeez: for the best answer possible, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). A minimal code example that compiles, runs, has no extraneous code unrelated to your problem (for example no ActionListener code unless code is necessary to show and remove the JPanel). Again, it must be small, small enough to post in its entirety here, it must be runnable and compilable by us without need of external dependencies such as images or databases.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels added sscce. Please help. See the problem is when I setvisible to false it hides but never shows it again. Even on setting it to true.

Comment: added sscce. Please help. See the problem is when I setvisible to false it hides but never shows it again. Even on setting it to true.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Got the answer, please leave it if you were trying. And thanks Sir for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setVisible(false)` rather than removing it, then when you want it to appear again, use `setVisible(true)`

Comment: setVisible(false) hides the panels, but again setting it to true, doesn't show it back.

Comment: @jeez: don't forget to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the **container** holding the components whenever components are added or removed. Be sure to do this after the change as this will tell the container's layout managers to re-layout its visible components, and the repaint will suggest to Swing's repaint manager that the container's view is "dirty" and needs to have the OS repaint it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels After adding, removing, I as showed in the code appended in the question, have used `revalidate()` and `repaint()`. I don't need that when i change visibility using setVisible. Right?

Comment: @jeez: yes, you sure do since by changing the visibility, the components will have to shift and be re-drawn. But again, this needs to be called on the *container* that holds the components, not the components that are being made visible or invisible themselves. Also strongly consider use of CardLayout as Camickr aptly suggests.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I like this design ;(. If the problem persists, I may have to consider card layout. But I really don't want to.

Comment: added sscce. Please help. See the problem is when I setvisible to false it hides but never shows it again. Even on setting it to true.

Comment: Another option would be to move all of this into another container that contains both the edit panel and the button panel simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

You are right, The Width of the Panel can be the cause, Just don't change the width of the Video Player, If the problem persist,
I would prefer you to use JLayeredPane, and on that pane add both the panels and use setVisible(true) and setVisible(false) for showing or hiding panels, that's an easy way and will not produce errors.
Give me your feedback about the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, please go through comments on Mukesh's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I once had same problem when i was using swings with NetBeans.. After struggling for few hours.. all i did was restarted the IDE .. and the problem was gone.. Just give a try

Comment: Thanks, Actually am not using NetBeans, but cmd. And I have tried recompiling and restarting. :)

Comment: i think since the buttons are still working.. code is right.. Problem as u assumed might be the overlapping..Why dont u make the edit button as small as possible with single character text on it so that the overlap is only on upload button.Then we can be atleast sure that overlap is either a problem or not..

Comment: Yes, the width thing is creating problem, Even when I have a single lettered button, 'E', still it shows panel same as in the question, with a greater width, and overlapping with player

Comment: added sscce. Please help. See the problem is when I setvisible to false it hides but never shows it again. Even on setting it to true.